# on shopware 6 I would like to know how to prevent an item from coming into my cart based on "custom name" added to it

Tags: php, shopware6

I am working with a subscriber, I work with two events

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
           AfterLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'onLineItemAdded',
            BeforeLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'beAdded',
        ];
    }
```

the BeforeLineItemAddedEvent triggers and captures the current state of the cart, meaning I am able to know what products are in the cart and see their customField names in their respective array.

the AfterLineItemAddedEvent triggers and captures the the incoming request mad when a user adds to cart, meaning I am able to know what products are in the incoming requests and see their customField names in their respective array.

I am trying to check the custom Fields of the products in this two scenarios or events specifically named "shipper" which exists as an array key "shipper_".

1. if it exists in the cart and does not exist in the incoming request I want to reject or a log a message.
2. if it dosent exist in the cart but exist in the incoming request I also want to reject or a log a message.
3. if it exists both in the cart and incoming request, don't reject or log a message.
4. 3. if it docent exists both in the cart and incoming request, don't reject or log a message

currently I'm doing this

onLineItemAdded, carries the custom fields for when the user adds to cart

```
 public function onLineItemAdded(AfterLineItemAddedEvent $event): void
{

$lineItems = $event-\>getLineItems();

    foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
        $this->processCustomFields($lineItem);
        $payload = $lineItem->getPayload();
        if (isset($payload['customFields'])) {
            $customFields = $payload['customFields'];
            $cartArray = json_decode(json_encode($customFields), true);
            $this->logger->info('The on fields:', $cartArray);
        }
    }
    }`
```

beAdded carries customfields for the current products in the cart

```
   public function beAdded(BeforeLineItemAddedEvent $event): void
    {
        $cart = $event->getCart();
        $lineItems = $cart->getLineItems();

        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
            $this->processCustomFields($lineItem);
            $payload = $lineItem->getPayload();
            if (isset($payload['customFields'])) {
                $customFields = $payload['customFields'];
                $cartArray = json_decode(json_encode($customFields), true);
                $this->logger->info('The before fields:', $cartArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

and processCustomFields acts as a processor and provides payloads for Both the above methods

```
    private function processCustomFields(LineItem $lineItem): void
    {
        $payload = $lineItem->getPayload();

        if (isset($payload['customFields'])) {
            $customFields = $payload['customFields'];
            //$cartArray = json_decode(json_encode($customFields), true);
            //$this->logger->info('The fields:', $cartArray);
        }

        
    }
```

I need to prevent my cart from having products e.g

1. product A which is in cart has (shipper) custom field while product B which is incoming dosent have a shipper custom field.
2. product A which is in cart dosent have (shipper) custom field while product B which is incoming has a shipper custom field.

These two scenarios above must not be permitted.

any other scenario is permissible, please help